# What issues could you hit when using Microsoft.AspNetCore.All in .NET Core 2?

Tags: .net-core

The recommendation is to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` in .NET Core 2 as it simplifies dependencies and uses tree shaker magic to not bloat what you publish.

I encountered one issue of moving to it: When using a library that references `StackExchange.Redis`, I ended up with a conflict as something within `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` references `StackExchange.Redis.StrongName`. See question [VS.NET 2017 forces using StackExchange.Redis 1.2.4.0 in ASP.NET 2.0 Core app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46029281) for further info. If I stick to referencing dependencies individually then I avoid this conflict and can compile.

Other than getting conflicts between things you don't use from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`, what are the other issues could you encounter because of this recommendation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pros and cons of Microsoft.AspNetCore.All metapackage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592816/pros-and-cons-of-microsoft-aspnetcore-all-metapackage)

Comment: That question has been closed as it is primarily opinion based. Edited question to focus specifically on issues that may arise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO it is not a usual issue since there are not many libraries out there published twice with the same types, in two different packages: one strongly named and one not. Especially being referenced by the metapackage `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.0`

You are definitely not the only one with this `StackExchange.Redis` issue (I stumbled across it twice already) but the maintainers are planning to [drop the `StrongName` package on version 2.0](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/528).

You can try dealing with it with the `extern alias` approach discussed [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4989).

A quick way around it is to target the same package AspNetCore targets (the StrongName one). In case it's just a project within a solution you work with, it's an easy hack.

Another is to target `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis`. That's what the metapackage depends on.

That's until SE.Redis releases version 2.0.0.